# Bootstrap dropdown data-toggle not showing in complicated nav setup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with my Bootstrap navbar button not showing the dropdown links when the screen is collapsed.

I have a navbar brand that hides on collapse but ever since i added a scrolling nav plugin my links dont show in dropdown. It is is also acting strangely in that if the page is below the level of the top section clicking the button just scrolls up to the top yet i cannot see what the conflict is.

here is a fiddle:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tokolosh/m3m99fhr/1/#run)

My HTML is like so:

```
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">   
<div id="twitterbootstrap">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                <a class="brand hidden-desktop page-scroll" href="#page-top">BrandHidden</a>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a class="brand visible-desktop page-scroll" href="#page-top">BrandVisible</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#about">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Link 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- Scrolling Nav JavaScript -->
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
</body>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: its complicated to me.... dont laugh im only new ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your custom css.  In the rule that you added for `.hidden-desktop` you added `position: relative`.  I'm not sure why you need position relative anyway but what it's doing is capturing the click event for the entire navbar.  You can see this by adding `pointer-events: none` to the rule and it will magically work.

The pointer-events property in css basically says to allow the mouse to penetrate the layers of your design and register click events on things that are otherwise obstructed by some higher layer.  Although adding `pointer-events: none` works to demonstrate the problem here, it only has IE support in version 11, so  I recommend removing the `position: relative` property.  There is no logical reason I can think to have position set given that the display is set to none.

```
.hidden-desktop {
    display: none !important;
    position:relative; /*remove this*/
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/m3m99fhr/7/.  I linked the Bootstrap files now in the external resources so that you can see it working in fiddle itself.

Comment: Thank you very very much this was the solution... Im still a webdev beginner and even moreso with bootstrap so thank you for your wonderful explanation. I still dont have the rep to upvote you but my thanks again

Answer (score 0):

How about bootstrap.css?

`Try this one:`http://jsfiddle.net/iboylmz/McHUc/41/

Comment: Thank you mate I am grateful for you taking the time to answer.